# Starting MySql Failed: check log for more info

Tags: mysql, innodb, mac-os-x

I just recently started using MAMP, PHPmyAdmin, and wordpress. When I try to restart the server in MAMP PRO by pressing the server icon in top right corner (mamp pro), I get a pop up that reads the error: "Starting MySQL failed. MySQl couldn't be started. Please check the log files for more information.

The log files read the following:

```
170525 19:13:52 mysqld_safe Logging to 
'/Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_error.log'.
170525 19:13:53 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases 
from /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql56
2017-05-25 19:13:53 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value 
is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server 
option (see documentation for more details).
2017-05-25 19:13:53 0 [Note] --secure-file-priv is set to NULL. 
Operations related to importing and exporting data are disabled
2017-05-25 19:13:53 0 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld 
(mysqld 5.6.35) starting as process 9486 ...
2017-05-25 19:13:53 9486 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 
because file system for /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP 
PRO/db/mysql56/ is case insensitive
2017-05-25 19:13:53 9486 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2017-05-25 19:13:53 9486 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count 
buffer pool pages
2017-05-25 19:13:53 9486 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is 
disabled
2017-05-25 19:13:53 9486 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC 
atomic builtins
2017-05-25 19:13:53 9486 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2017-05-25 19:13:53 9486 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 
1.2.8
2017-05-25 19:13:53 9486 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2017-05-25 19:13:53 9486 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, 
size = 128.0M
2017-05-25 19:13:53 9486 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of 
buffer pool
2017-05-25 19:13:53 9486 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format 
is Barracuda.
2017-05-25 19:13:53 9486 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 0 
and 0 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 11639103 
in the ib_logfiles!
2017-05-25 19:13:53 9486 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown 
normally!
2017-05-25 19:13:53 9486 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2017-05-25 19:13:53 9486 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace 
information from the .ibd files...
2017-05-25 19:13:53 9486 [ERROR] InnoDB: Attempted to open a 
previously opened tablespace. Previous tablespace 
mysql/innodb_index_stats uses space ID: 2 at filepath: 
./mysql/innodb_index_stats.ibd. Cannot open tablespace 
wp_demo/wp_usermeta which uses space ID: 2 at filepath: . 
/wp_demo/wp_usermeta.ibd
2017-05-25 19:13:53 7fff9ac213c0  InnoDB: Operating system error 
number 2 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create
InnoDB: directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table tablespace file 
./wp_demo/wp_usermeta.ibd
InnoDB: We do not continue the crash recovery, because the table may 
become
InnoDB: corrupt if we cannot apply the log records in the InnoDB log 
to it.
InnoDB: To fix the problem and start mysqld:
InnoDB: 1) If there is a permission problem in the file and mysqld 
cannot
InnoDB: open the file, you should modify the permissions.
InnoDB: 2) If the table is not needed, or you can restore it from a 
backup,
InnoDB: then you can remove the .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a 
normal
InnoDB: crash recovery and ignore that table.
InnoDB: 3) If the file system or the disk is broken, and you cannot 
remove
InnoDB: the .ibd file, you can set innodb_force_recovery > 0 in 
my.cnf
InnoDB: and force InnoDB to continue crash recovery here.
170525 19:13:53 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file 
/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended
170525 19:16:02 mysqld_safe Logging to 
'/Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_error.log'.
170525 19:16:02 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases 
from /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql56
2017-05-25 19:16:03 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value 
is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server 
option (see documentation for more details).
2017-05-25 19:16:03 0 [Note] --secure-file-priv is set to NULL. 
Operations related to importing and exporting data are disabled
2017-05-25 19:16:03 0 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld 
(mysqld 5.6.35) starting as process 10315 ...
2017-05-25 19:16:03 10315 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 
because file system for /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP 
PRO/db/mysql56/ is case insensitive
2017-05-25 19:16:03 10315 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2017-05-25 19:16:03 10315 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count 
buffer pool pages
2017-05-25 19:16:03 10315 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is 
disabled
2017-05-25 19:16:03 10315 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC 
atomic builtins
2017-05-25 19:16:03 10315 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2017-05-25 19:16:03 10315 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 
1.2.8
2017-05-25 19:16:03 10315 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2017-05-25 19:16:03 10315 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, 
size = 128.0M
2017-05-25 19:16:03 10315 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of 
buffer pool
2017-05-25 19:16:03 10315 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file 
format is Barracuda.
2017-05-25 19:16:03 10315 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 0 
and 0 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 11639103 
in the ib_logfiles!
2017-05-25 19:16:03 10315 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown 
normally!
2017-05-25 19:16:03 10315 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2017-05-25 19:16:03 10315 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace 
information from the .ibd files...
2017-05-25 19:16:03 10315 [ERROR] InnoDB: Attempted to open a 
previously opened tablespace. Previous tablespace 
mysql/innodb_index_stats uses space ID: 2 at filepath: 
./mysql/innodb_index_stats.ibd. Cannot open tablespace 
wp_demo/wp_usermeta which uses space ID: 2 at filepath: 
./wp_demo/wp_usermeta.ibd
2017-05-25 19:16:03 7fff9ac213c0  InnoDB: Operating system error 
number 2 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create
InnoDB: directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table tablespace file 
./wp_demo/wp_usermeta.ibd
InnoDB: We do not continue the crash recovery, because the table may 
become
InnoDB: corrupt if we cannot apply the log records in the InnoDB log 
to it.
InnoDB: To fix the problem and start mysqld:
InnoDB: 1) If there is a permission problem in the file and mysqld 
cannot
InnoDB: open the file, you should modify the permissions.
InnoDB: 2) If the table is not needed, or you can restore it from a 
backup,
InnoDB: then you can remove the .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a 
normal
InnoDB: crash recovery and ignore that table.
InnoDB: 3) If the file system or the disk is broken, and you cannot 
remove
InnoDB: the .ibd file, you can set innodb_force_recovery > 0 in 
my.cnf
InnoDB: and force InnoDB to continue crash recovery here.
170525 19:16:03 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file 
/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended
170525 19:17:53 mysqld_safe Logging to 
'/Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_error.log'.
170525 19:17:53 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases 
from /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql56
2017-05-25 19:17:53 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value 
is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server 
option (see documentation for more details).
2017-05-25 19:17:53 0 [Note] --secure-file-priv is set to NULL. 
Operations related to importing and exporting data are disabled
2017-05-25 19:17:53 0 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld 
(mysqld 5.6.35) starting as process 11086 ...
2017-05-25 19:17:53 11086 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 
because file system for /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP 
PRO/db/mysql56/ is case insensitive
2017-05-25 19:17:53 11086 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2017-05-25 19:17:53 11086 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count 
buffer pool pages
2017-05-25 19:17:53 11086 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is 
disabled
2017-05-25 19:17:53 11086 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC 
atomic builtins
2017-05-25 19:17:53 11086 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2017-05-25 19:17:53 11086 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 
1.2.8
2017-05-25 19:17:53 11086 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2017-05-25 19:17:53 11086 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, 
size = 128.0M
2017-05-25 19:17:53 11086 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of 
buffer pool
2017-05-25 19:17:53 11086 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file 
format is Barracuda.
2017-05-25 19:17:53 11086 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 0 
and 0 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 11639103 
in the ib_logfiles!
2017-05-25 19:17:53 11086 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown 
normally!
2017-05-25 19:17:53 11086 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2017-05-25 19:17:53 11086 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace 
information from the .ibd files...
2017-05-25 19:17:53 11086 [ERROR] InnoDB: Attempted to open a 
previously opened tablespace. Previous tablespace
```

Comment: Log says `2017-05-25 19:13:53 9486 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!` so you probably have killed MySQL or it crashed last time. If you don't wanna do recovering everyday, find out why MySQL did not shut down properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change/add below entry in my.cnf and restart.

> [mysqld]
>
> innodb_force_recovery = 1

If this works, try to take a mysqldump and keep it safe side. And recreate a fresh installation with correct settings and remember to remove the entry  innodb_force_recovery.

If this doesn't work, increase the value `from 1 upto 3` and see if it works.

Since I'm not sure about the history of this server. You may need to verify your innodb_log_file_size set correctly as [per recommended values.](https://tools.percona.com/wizard)

Comment: Forcing recovery without knowing the root cause might result in data loss. Please perform a backup of you files, before you consider `innodb_force_recovery`.

Comment: If 3 is not enough I would suggest 4 - in my understanding, it is only dangerous for indexes. For many years the documentation considered 4 as a safe value.